# Chrome not refreshing background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have some issues using a carousel inside a dropdown with chrome.

I don't understand why the code works fine with `firefox` but when using `chrome` the image on the background doesn't keep the `position:fixed` attribute, it will "refresh" its position only when I hover above the menu item containing the carousel.

This will create a really bad effect when scrolling up since the background image won't reset its position leaving a white space.

I don't know if it is a known problem, I don't have time to put all the code right now, will do if needed.

Comment: Well.. We need the code to help, so the code is needed.

Comment: Fine to have some working link like jsfiddle...

Comment: We do really need the code, but you could try background-attachment: fixed; http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp